# How can iOS application interact with an Ethereum wallet

Tags: react-native, ethereum, react-native-ios, web3js, metamask

I have a dapp for web application. Users have metamask installed in the Chrome browser. They make transactions using metamask. Now I want the same application to be developed in iOS using react-native. How to develop this? For browser when users want to make any transaction simply metamask pop ups and asks for confirmation.

How about in mobile devices? How they are going to install metmask in the devices and make transactions in mobile device.  Is is possible to achieve this? How can I develop this app?

Comment: Did you get success on this? I am struggling with exact same scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Your iOS app can communicate with iOS wallets using [WalletConnect mobile linking](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking). This fulfils a similar functionality as MetaMask pop-up on desktop environments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't need metamask for your application. (And I am yet to see someone use it in an app built in React Native.)

Metamask is essentially a wallet which 'injects' into various services on the web. But it is nothing more than a wallet that manages your identit(y/ies).

The features you'd need in your React app would need:

1. Managing identities (private and public keys.)
2. Ability to sign transactions.

Then you might want to use extra features such as:

- Importing keys
- Updating balances
- Recording transasctions, etc.

If you're using web3.js, then you need to start here: [web3.eth.accounts](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html) and look into wallets on the [same page](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet).

Comment: Thanks for the reply daveldito. How do i add accounts to the wallet. Which wallet i can integrate to my app. If i use web3js then it needs some provider right. Where do i get that provider in mobile app?

Comment: You'll have to use web3.js to run the 'wallet' services. I'm not aware of one that you can use right away. Yes, you do need a provider. Depending on the app, you set up your own node which the app will interact with, or you can use infura.io right away. I'd suggest the latter due to ease of use.

Comment: Don't get confused with a provider and using it with a wallet. You can of course use a provider (node) for wallet as well, but you don't have to (and I won't recommend unless you fully trust the node). You merely need to maintain key value pairs, be able to sign a transaction (locally) and then send it off to a provider- the callback will give you the status or you can just query.

Comment: Daveldito thanks for your reply. My exact question is just like how we have metamask in webbrowser what we have in mobile so that when i use web3.currentProvider it should return some valid instance.

Comment: Any code samples for this? I have a PWA in iOS that I want to work with metamask

Answer (score 0):

For React Native, you can use the Moralis SDK https://moralis.io/

If you're developing a native app with Swift, you can use the v1 WalletConnect SDK https://github.com/WalletConnect/WalletConnectSwift.

Also, I'm working on a package (on top of WC) that already has all the configuration for it: https://github.com/maurovz/Glaip